# Terminal does not accept pasted or typed lines of more than 1024 characters

Tags: command-line, terminal, osx, limit, stdin

When I enter text on stdin in an OS X Terminal, a single line is limited to 1024 characters. For example, `cat > /dev/null` beeps after I type (or paste) a line longer than this, and refuses to accept more characters. A problematic example is when I want to count characters from pasted text with `cat | wc -c`: the `cat` blocks at the first long line.

This seems to be a general problem with pasting to stdin. Can this observed stdin limitation of 1024 characters per line be removed or pushed to a higher limit?

I need this because I want to paste text that has lines longer than 1024 characters.

I could also use a "heredoc" `<< EOT` and paste my long lines without any problem, but then the text appears in my shell history, which I don't want.

Comment: That's annoying. I guess the Heredoc approach is a tolerable work-around, since you can tell the shell to not add a  command line that starts with a space. See [Is there any way to keep a command from being added to your history?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6094/is-there-any-way-to-keep-a-command-from-being-added-to-your-history) for details for various shells, including zsh.

Comment: This is a badly phrased question.  _In the Z shell_ the limit is **not** 1024 characters.  You're actually talking about a limit that is not implemented by the Z Shell, nor in force when the Z shell is the program that is reading input from the terminal.  In this case, it is `cat` that is doing the reading, and the Z shell isn't involved.  This ground has been covered before, with `cat`, at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131105/ .

Comment: Call `pbpaste` instead of pasting. (That's on OSX; under X11, call `xsel` or `xclip`.)

Comment: @JdeBP My question was obviously _not_ about zsh but about the `cat` command not working like I needed: I was giving details about my environment (zsh, OS X Terminal), in case they mattered.

Comment: @Gilles Your solution deserves to be put in one of the answers. I will let you do it if you want, otherwise I will do it: it can really be useful.

Comment: @Gilles A `pbpaste`/`xclip` solution should mention the fact that it does not work on a remote host, since it does not have the same clipboard as the local host.

Comment: you can use a clipboard manager as mentioned, or you can switch to non-canonical input as mentioned, or you can try a program that can do that stuff for you. You might have luck with `less -f /dev/tty | out` or better with `ex - ^Mo^M<paste>^[:wq!` where the ^escapes in the last stand in for real keypresses. I think `less` should basically set the terminal to raw and handle its own line wrapping - and definitely `ex/vi/open` do... well, definitely `vi/open` do *(`ex` is definitely canonical)*.

Comment: @mikeserv Thank you for the ideas. The `less - f /dev/tty` does not work, for me, unfortunately. Another idea, though, for remote host pasting, is to uuencode first (so as to get short lines).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Probably a limit of the terminal device line discipline internal line editor buffer.

You should be able to enter long lines by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> in the middle of it (so the currently entered part be sent to `cat` and the line editor flushed), or by disabling that line editor altogether.

For instance, if using `zsh`:

```
STTY=-icanon cat > file
```

Note that then you can't use <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or any other editing capability. You'd also need to press <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to stop  `cat`.

With other shells:

```
s=$(stty -g); stty -icanon; cat > file
```

Followed by:

```
stty "$s"
```

Or just:

```
stty -icanon; cat > file
stty sane
```

Of course, things like

```
cat | wc -l
```

or

```
wc -l
```

won't work. Because <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> kills all the processes in the foreground process group.

You could do:

```
STTY=-icanon cat | (trap '' INT; wc -l)
```

Or [as suggested by @mikeserv](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205086/52934):

```
STTY='eol " "' wc -l
```

That way, the buffer will be flushed every time you enter space. You're still in canonical mode, so you can still edit *words* (as opposed to lines) and use <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> to signify EOF.

Or:

```
STTY='-icanon min 0 time 30' wc -l
```

EOF will come 3 seconds after you stop typing. Or:

```
STTY=-icanon sed -n '/^EOF$/q;p' | wc -l
```

And enter `EOF` (the 3 letters on a line on its own) to end the input.

As [suggested by Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131274), where possible (as in generally *not* a telnet/ssh session for instance), use `pbpaste` instead of pasting. (That's on OSX; under X11, call `xsel` or `xclip`.):

```
pbpaste | wc -l
```

That will also avoid problems with some control characters (like `^C`) that may be found in the copy-paste buffer.

Comment: This does indeed allow me to paste long lines. However, it does not work for the general case of pasting to stdin: for example, `STTY=-icanon cat | wc -c` does not produce any result (I guess that the necessary Ctrl-C kills `wc`).

Comment: @EOL - the CTRL-C isn't necessary - use the eof char - CTRL-D by default. Actually, nevermind CTRL-D - but you can use CTRL-J to end the line. Alternatively - and probably not a great idea - set `noflsh`. If you use `dd` rather than `cat` you'll always get your *(byte)* count anyway - and `dd` always writes on a SIGINT as well.

Comment: @mikeserv I am not sure what you mean, about "Ctrl-C not being necessary". How do you indicate the end of the input, with `STTY=-icanon cat | wc -c`?? (The solution in the answer seems to be to kill `cat`, but this prevents `wc` from running, apparently.)

Comment: @EOL - Well, i figured `wc` was waiting on the end of a line. INT and TSTP will both flush i/o - but TSTP can be recovered. CTRL-Z + `fg` may help - but can you not just do CTRL-J? *(it's the newline char)*. Alternatively you can: `cat | ( trap '' INT; wc -c)`, but that assumes `wc` is well-behaved enough to die at the end of its input - probably a safe-assumption, though, given its purpose. `dd`, as mentioned, will always write on INT, and `tee` can be told to `-i`gnore interrupts. Honestly, your heredoc idea was best, though - look at `HIST_NO_STORE` in `man zshall`. `sh`ly: `set -o nolog`.

Comment: Thank you for all the ideas. Ctrl-J does not quit `cat`, so `wc` is never run (the pasted text already contains many newlines, so it is fortunate that `cat` does not quit on newline :) ). Your `trap` idea works (after STTY=…). It's a little bit involved, for simply counting characters, though. On a local machine, `pbpaste | wc -c` and friends is good.

Comment: @EOL, see edit for other alternatives.

Comment: @EOL - i dunno.. i don't think there are newlines in the cut buffer - which, i think, is the source of your problem. I think probably there are line-feeds or returns - or, actually, since i think Macs *only* honor returns by default, maybe the source of the problem is reversed? Anyway, if there are end-of-line chars in the cut buffer the canonical terminal should not hang as it does - each \n/\r *(whichever)* should flush the buffer when pasted. Switch `wc` to `-l` and see what it reports, also consider setting a literal `stty eol <char>` and/or `i(cr|nl)(nl|cr)` as appropriate.

Comment: @EOL - I wrote an answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205086/52934) about how the `stty eol` setting might be used in some situations to overcome a canonical line-discipline's maximum line-length. It may be applicable to your problem as well.

Comment: Why did I never have this problem with linux and bash.